# Prove a DAG can be obtained by an undirected graph's longest cycle

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, hamiltonian-path, orientation, directed-graphs

Let *G(V, E)* be a finite undirected graph and let *κ* be its longest undirected cycle.

1. Prove that it is always possible to obtain an orientation *ω(κ)* in which  *κ* is topologically sorted and hence its last edge (from node 1 to node N) is inverted.
2. Prove that given  *ω(κ)* it is always possible to orient the remainder of the graph as to build a DAG.

For example, in a 5-node graph with its hamiltonian path as *κ*:

[image]

The proof of (1) seems intuitive: one can always direct the edges of an undirected cycle as to form a directed cycle and then invert one of the edges at random. This causes a topological sort starting at the node on the origin of the new edge. I have no clue on the proof of (2). I'm new to graph theory and still lack the knowledge to write proofs formally, so I'm hoping to learn a bit more on this with this question too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assign different numbers as labels to the vertices, such that your chosen cycle visits vertices in increasing order.

It doesn't matter which labels you choose for vertices that are *not* in your cycle, as long as the labels are all distinct.

Orient each edge in the direction of increasing numbers.

Comment: This looks like an algorithm. Is it enough for as a proof? How should I prove its correctness?

Comment: @GabrielRebello: It is probably not enough for an actual proof in most classroom contexts, but it contains the main idea of a proof. I'm leaving the filling-in of proof details to you, but it is a quite simple verification that the orientation that results will have the properties you want.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. I'm completely new into verifications so I'm willing to learn. Is there a good reference for this kind of problem that I can use to start writing and understanding the proof?